# What access required to create azure function app?

Tags: azure-functions

We new to Azure platform. We are exploring to create a function on a subscription where we need to develop Azure AD B2C custom policy.

We do not know what access request we need to place in order to create azure function?

Can you please let us know what access needed to create azure function??

Need to know access requirement to create azure function

Answer (score 0):

To create an Azure Function in your Azure subscription, you'll need "Contributor" role. This role is required to perform most function app-level tasks.  In Scope, you can set the at which level you want to assign the role. Scope can be set to Subscription or Resource group or Resource.

For reference on the similar question, you can check this [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/669276/azure-function-rbac) post.

[image]

[image]